# NullPointerException on my app its keep crushing android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore in my app and when I run it, it keeps crashing.

Code:

```
RecyclerView RecyclerView;
ArrayList<Sabah> sabahArrayList;
Myadapter myadapter;
FirebaseFirestore db;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_azkarsabah);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
    progressDialog.show();


    RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    sabahArrayList = new ArrayList<Sabah>();
    myadapter = new Myadapter(azkarsabah.this,sabahArrayList);

    RecyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

    EventChangeListener();

}

private void EventChangeListener() {

    db.collection("Sabah").orderBy("sabahzekarnum", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            if (error != null){

                if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                Log.e("Error" , error.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){

                if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    sabahArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Sabah.class));


                }

                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Sabah> sabahArrayList;

public Myadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Sabah> sabahArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sabahArrayList = sabahArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Myadapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_azkarsabah,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myadapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Sabah sabah = sabahArrayList.get(position);

    holder.sabahzekershow.setText(sabah.sabahzekershow);
    holder.sabahzekarnum.setText(String.valueOf(sabah.sabahzekarnum));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sabahArrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView sabahzekarnum,sabahzekershow;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sabahzekarnum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sabahzekarnum);
        sabahzekershow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sabahzekershow);
    }
}
```

}

In logcat it give me this problems. For Whitelisted problem I tried to free my phone space since I use phone while running the app. I also cleaned the project but I still have the same problem
and other problems. I did not understand what the problem is.

```
  2022-03-15 08:27:15.140 9732-9732/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2022-03-15 08:27:15.142 9732-9732/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1


    2022-03-15 08:27:18.087 9732-9732/com.example.tasbeeh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tasbeeh, PID: 9732
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tasbeeh.Myadapter.onBindViewHolder(Myadapter.java:38)
        at com.example.tasbeeh.Myadapter.onBindViewHolder(Myadapter.java:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2856)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1904)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8535)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-03-15 08:27:18.088 9732-9732/com.example.tasbeeh E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Cross check the IDs of `activity_azkarsabah` with the `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are inflating wrong layout in the `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

```
public Myadapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_azkarsabah,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
```

Here in `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_azkarsabah,parent,false)`, you are trying to inflate `R.layout.activity_azkarsabah` but according to me you supposed to inflate Item View layout like `R.layout.item_view`.

Maybe I am wrong as I haven't see your `activity_azkarsabah.xml` file.

Comment: thank you very much !! you are right the problem was with activity_azkarsabah

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems in **MyAdapter**
You are inflating layout of an activity

```
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_azkarsabah,parent,false);
```

But you should make another layout for RecyclerView items

Make another xml layout like **item_myadapter** Then

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_myadapter,parent,false);
```

Make sure to have textview in this layout with same id as

```
sabahzekarnum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sabahzekarnum);
sabahzekershow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sabahzekershow);
```

Layout **item_myadapter** looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sabahzekarnum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sabahzekershow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If the above didn't helps then you may be getting NULL values in your list then try

```
holder.sabahzekershow.setText(""+sabah.sabahzekershow);
holder.sabahzekarnum.setText(""+String.valueOf(sabah.sabahzekarnum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems in MyAdapter You are set data on textview

```kotlin
holder.sabahzekershow.setText(sabah.sabahzekershow);
holder.sabahzekarnum.setText(String.valueOf(sabah.sabahzekarnum));
```

First you check `sabah.sabahzekershow` OR `sabah.sabahzekarnum`
in this two if anything one is `null` then the app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put One Condition When You Are Show Your Details As If Else, If Data Is Null Then Show Whatever And If Data Is Not Null Then Show Data

```
if (sabah.sabahzekershow == null){
    holder.sabahzekershow.setText("");
}else {
    holder.sabahzekershow.setText(sabah.sabahzekershow);
}
if (sabah.sabahzekarnum == null){
    holder.sabahzekarnum.setText("");
}else {
    holder.sabahzekarnum.setText(String.valueOf(sabah.sabahzekarnum));
}
```

Using This If Else Condition If Data Is Null But Your App Is Not Crash